# How do I simulate user input to a console application from Unit Test project?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, winapi, input, rpn

I am trying to write a text processing console application in C++ and I have met Windows API for the first time. But before defining a grammar or using the existing bison/flex or boost tools I want to realize a TDD approach and write all tests and interfaces (except here I have put a dummy test having hard time with even launching the .exe from test code).

My design is following:
- Unit tests from native test project call a `CreateProcess()` function from Windows API that I have put into `CreateProc()` macro. Example of this macro (I have slightly modified it) is taken from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx). Idea of this macro is execute my console application but from unit test to simulate user input after. Here is the code:

```
#define MYEXE L"my_Console_Application_Path.exe"
#ifdef MYEXE
PROCESS_INFORMATION CreateProc() {
STARTUPINFO si = { 0 };
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = { 0 };

ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
si.cb = sizeof(si);
ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));
if (CreateProcess
    (
        MYEXE,
        NULL,
        NULL,          
        NULL,          
        NULL, //,         
        CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,          
        NULL,         
        NULL,          
        &si,            
        &pi            
    ) 
    ) 
    {
        CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
        CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
        return pi; 
    } 
else 
    {
        std::cout << "Unable to execute.";
        return pi;
    }


}
#endif
```

Test that runs and "uses" my console application is defined:

```
TEST_CLASS(UnitTest1)
{
public:

    TEST_METHOD(Should_Open_Console)
    {
        PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo = CreateProc();
        Assert::IsTrue(processInfo.dwProcessId); // check if process id is not zero
    }
```

`main` function of console application looks like this:

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << "test that function is running" << std::endl;
    std::string myline = "";
    std::getline(std::cin, myline); 
    return 0;
}
```

Basically my `CreateProc()` sucessfully launches the executable. However I want tests to simulate user input that `main` is listening to with `getline(...)`. After I am going to parse this sequence with some parser.

How could I simulate this input within current console process? Of course I will be grateful if you can advise me some concrete instruments (is [this `SendInput()` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908262/simulating-input-using-the-sendinput-function) the best way to simulate input?) and the most important - how it should be done in terms of design? Ideally I see a string defined in a Unit test and passed through `CreateProcess()` as argument to main and the same string is somehow read from console after. Kind of this:

```
TEST_CLASS(UnitTest1)
{
public:
// parsing Hola as Hello
    TEST_METHOD(Should_Return_Hello_If_Input_Equals_to_Hola)
    {
        CreateProc("Hola");
        Assert::AreEqual(Console.readline() = "Hello"); // dummy code
    }
```

Am I right? If yes, how could I actually do it? (if you can correct code snippets it would be great)

Comment: you can redirect input/output to pipe. and in parent process, write to pipe, what you want to be input

Comment: [Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499(v=vs.85).aspx)